# php login screen error

Tags: php, android

```
    <?php

/*
 * Following code will update a product information
 * A product is identified by product id (pid)
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// check for required fields
if (isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['pass'])) {

    $eml = $_POST['email'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];
    $e = "$eml";

    // include db connect class


    // connecting to db
   $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=quotes;charset=utf8', 'Sidd');

    // mysql update row with matched pid
    $result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE email='$e'");

    // check if row inserted or not
    if ($result) {

       $response["success"] = 1; 
      $response["message"] = "Login Successful";
    //    while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    //    $response["uid"] = $row["uid"];
          // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }


    else {
           // failed to insert row
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);

    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

***Error***

Android app always return Success=1 and login successful whether the entered Email id is right or wrong! As such whether email id exist in database or not. what am i missing? :/ .................... :(

And Also inform whether the commented code will work?!!
Please help

Comment: Question has been solved. Thanks everyone for there valuable time. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
 $result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE email='$e'");
    if ($result) {....}
```

with

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE email='$e'");
$row_count = $result->rowCount(); //number of rows with same email
if($row_count >0)  {...}
```

Comment: if($result) will give output that, it is executed or not. It will be always true if your DB connection is fine.

Answer (score 0):

PDO `query` method returns `object`. `Object` is always compared to `true`. **ALWAYS**.

`query` method can return `false` but only in case there is an **error**. But having no values that corresponds to given email is not an error.

Comment: Ooooo... Im new to this PDO. How to correct it? What should i do now?

Comment: `Var_dump($result)`, what it shows for correct email and incorrect. And decide how to check.

Comment: Ok i would add some other check also but.. How to retrieve a single key 'uid'  from table after checking email and passwrd?

Comment: Uncomment and test it, what's the problem?

Comment: its not returning the the value to android!! :/